# Is there a way to paginate through individual template elements?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Problem:

I currently have a template that has multiple nested divs which would contain different list items. Currently if I click the next button on one of the elements, the full page reloads and now all of the elements or on the next or previous page.

Code:

Main template code in a div

```
      {% include "users/activities.html" with activities=action1 table_title='Signups' action_verb='action1' %}
      {% include "users/activities.html" with activities=action2 table_title='Actions' %}
      {% include "users/activities.html" with activities=action3 table_title='Actions 2'%}
```

Activity template code with pagination:

```
    {% if activities.has_other_pages %}
    <div class="paginationWrap">
      <ul class="pagination">
        {% if activities.has_previous %}
          <li><a href="?page={{ activities.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
        {% else %}
          <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% for i in activities.paginator.page_range %}
          {% if activities.number == i %}
            <li class="active"><span> {{ i }} </span></li>
          {% else %}
            <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if activities.has_next %}
          <li><a href="?page={{ activities.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
        {% else %}
          <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
```

Goal:

The ability to click in one div and not have all of divs return page change.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the whole page loading, develop an api with pagination option, then hit it using ajax request to update your data using ajax request.

```
#python
class ActivitiesView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        activity_details = Activities.objects.filter(user=request.user) # or any other query
        paginator = Paginator()
        response = paginator.generate_response(activity_details, ActivitySerializer, request)
        return response


   #js
       $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "{% url ur_url %}",
            data: "page="+pageNum,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                el = $('#friends-data');
                update_div(data.json);
            }
        });
```

You can check this also [DRF PAGINATION](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/)

Check this page also discussing [using django views](http://fromzerotocodehero.blogspot.com/2011/07/django-ajax-tutorial-part-2-ajax.html)